# Combine multiple text files into one

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a simple program that will combine multiple text files into one.  Basically, they are upgrade scripts.  So there's a "upgrade from" combo box and a "upgrade to" combo box.  I've managed to so far have the program read the directory to see what version scripts there are in the directory and sort them in ascending order.

What I'm having trouble with is combing the multiple files together.  I've managed to code it so it combines two scripts into one but it's hardcoded in.  I want the program to select the correct scripts without it being hardcoded.  Can anyone help?

This code is fine which populates the combo boxes based on the files listed in a directory and sorts them in ascending order:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim scriptcount As Integer
    counter = 0
    scriptcount = 0
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        counter = counter + 1
        version(counter) = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
        versionfilepath(counter) = "C:\itcd\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
    Next
    scriptcount = counter
    Do While counter >= 1
        cmbFrom.Items.Add(version(counter))
        cmbTo.Items.Add(version(counter))
        counter = counter - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

***This part I need help with.***

```
Private Sub butGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butGenerate.Click
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim currentversionnumber As Integer
    Dim script1() As String
    Dim script2() as String
    Dim combinedLines As New List(Of String)

    script1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\itcd\scripts\519.sql")
    script2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\itcd\scripts\520.sql")


    For linePos As Integer = 0 To System.Math.Max(script1.Length, script2.Length) - 1
        If linePos < script1.Length Then combinedLines.Add(script1(linePos))
        If linePos < script2.Length Then combinedLines.Add(script2(linePos))
    Next
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\itcd\scripts\new.sql", combinedLines.ToArray())
End Sub
```

I would like to create some sort of loop to if reads all the files that are selected then combine them into one file called new.sql without any hardcoding of the filepaths.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the file paths selected in the UI?

Comment: Instead of `ReadAllLines()` would you be willing to use `ReadAllText()`?  It might make things easier.

Comment: The file paths are not selected in the UI.  It's hard coded into the program which I can always change at a later date if needed.

Comment: Yes, I would be willing to use ReadAllText().  Do you know how I can fix it?  I'm not really familiar with ReadAllText.